# localStorage is not defined in next js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-redux, local-storage

I am using next.js for frontend. I want to get user from localStorage, but as next.js is a server-side rendring, I can't get localStorage. What should I do so I can get localStorage?

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import authService from "./authService";

const getUserfromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("user")
  ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"))
  : null;

const initialState = {
  user: getUserfromLocalStorage,
  isError: false,
  isLoading: false,
  isSuccess: false,
  message: "",
};

export const login = createAsyncThunk('auth/login', async (user, thunkAPI) => {
  try {
    return await authService.login(user);
  } catch (error) {
    return thunkAPI.rejectWithValue(error);
  }
});

export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(login.pending, (state) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
      })
      .addCase(login.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.user = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(login.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.isError = true;
        state.isSuccess = false;
        state.user = null;
      });
  },
});

export default authSlice.reducer;
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because you are trying to access client side variable - **window.localStorage** on server where **window** doesn't exist.

```
const getUserfromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null;
```

Here you should first check whether **window** is defined or not.

```
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const getUserfromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null;
}
```

**OR** you can check if window is defined using **optional chaining**

```
const getUserfromLocalStorage = window?.localStorage?.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null;
```

Here more "React" like solution would be to use hooks like **useEffect** to perform this action.

```
import { useEffect } from "react";

useEffect(() => {
  const getUserfromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null;
}, []);
```

Comment: i used if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  const getUserfromLocalStorage = localStorage.getItem("user") ? JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) : null;
}  , but i cant take value outside of if statement . i have to use  getUserfromLocalStorage in  initialState .

Comment: @nishikantsingh store initialState in a `useState` object, then use `useEffect` to `setInitialState(prev => { return { ...prev, user: newValue } }`. Does that solve your problem?

Comment: @nishikantsingh That can be solved with Optional chaining such as in 3rd code snippet of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I still got `ReferenceError: window is not defined` when trying to do the check on the window object.

```js
if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}
```

What worked for me was using optional chaining on the global object to access the window object.

```js
if (global?.window !== undefined) {
  // Now it's safe to access window and localStorage
  localStorage.setItem('token', token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this topic but what I was looking for was a ready-to-use react hook for localStorage.

For anyone looking for the same thing, here it is :

```
function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const isLocalStorageAvailable =
    typeof window !== "undefined" && window.localStorage;

  const storedValue = isLocalStorageAvailable
    ? localStorage.getItem(key)
    : null;

  const initial = storedValue ? JSON.parse(storedValue) : initialValue;

  const [value, setValue] = useState(initial);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isLocalStorageAvailable) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(value));
    }
  }, [key, value, isLocalStorageAvailable]);

  const setStoredValue = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue);
    if (isLocalStorageAvailable) {
      localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(newValue));
    }
  };

  return [value, setStoredValue];
}
```

This hook can be used the same way as useState hook, but the stored values must be serializable.

A conditional return based on typeof window being undefined can lead to runtime errors because Next.js does not like having different values on the server and client sides. With this function, which stores the localStorage getItem result in a React state, it should prevent such occurrences.

Answer (score -1):

Use

Const localStorageData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") || "{}") || null