# Do i have to define localStorage in NextJS 14?

Tags: next.js

I am trying to a Dark mode functionality based on localStorage in my website. But i a getting **ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined** in the terminal and when i tried to console log the value i get "null" when the page loads for the first time.

I have added the code below.

```js
"use client";

import { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function Darkmode() {

  const [theme, setTheme] = useState(
    localStorage.getItem("theme") ? localStorage.getItem("theme") : "light"
  );

  const handleTheme = (e) => {
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setTheme("dark");
    } else {
      setTheme("light");
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("theme", theme);
    const localTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
    document.querySelector("html").setAttribute("data-theme", localTheme);
  }, [theme]);

  console.log(localStorage.getItem("theme"));

  return (
    <>
      // component here
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [localStorage is not defined in next js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76070793/localstorage-is-not-defined-in-next-js)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are facing happens because every component, also client components are pre-rendered on the server and by setting the initial state inside your `useState` call you encounter a reference error. Here is what this code should look like instead:

```js
"use client";

import { useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function DarkMode() {
  const [theme, setTheme] = useState("light");

  const toggleTheme = useCallback(() => {
    setTheme(prev => {      
      // update your state via callback, this gives you the option
      // to access the previous state and set the localStorage value
      const nextTheme = prev === "light" ? "dark" : "light";
      localStorage.setItem("theme", nextTheme);
      return nextTheme;
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // set the initial theme value when component mounts
    // but only when the window object is defined
    if (typeof window === undefined) return;
    setTheme(localStorage?.getItem("theme") ?? "light");
  }, []);

  return <button onClick={toggleTheme}>{theme}</button>;
}
```

As you can see I have optimized your code by wrapping the toggle theme function inside a callback and only set the initial value when the component is on the client side.